# CSS: Keep Button On The Same Position on The Background When Resizing Window

Tags: html, wordpress, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to design a page in the style of an info-graphic, in Wordpress.

I have the time-line set as the background and then i precisely position the buttons to match the background. All good and well until i start resizing the browser's window - the buttons get totally misplaced.

I tried creating two columns and placing the buttons in the first. They keep their position until, because the window is shrinking and this is a responsive theme that I'm using, the second column gets moved underneath the first one. At this point the buttons are getting misplaced again.

I've tried toying with various css settings like position: relative, absolute and so on but to no avail. Is there a way to obtain what i need?

Thank you,
Vlad

Answer (score 0):

For fixed width , you have to use pixels not ems or percentages .

For the positions , Firet adjust the float or the position of the div or section containing that button which move with his parent in the responsive theme in wordpress .